# Why are every finite language decidable?

Tags: computer-science, regular-language, turing-machines

I don't understand why every finite language is decidable. For example, if I have an infinite set of strings L over an alphabet E, why is there a Turing Machine M that decides L? I understand the definition of decidable; however, why is every finite language decidable? Does there every exist a finite language that is not accepted?

EDIT: Any proof on this that I can go through is also appreciated

Comment: "An infinite set of strings $L$ over an alphabet $E$" is precisely _not_ a finite language!

Comment: typo I meant finite

Comment: You have to decide what you mean by finite:  are you saying every string in the language is finite, or that the number of strings in the language is finite, or both?

Answer (score 9):

In a finite language there will be a maximal length of any string in the language -- call it $n$.

There are finitely many possible strings of at most $n$ symbols. Construct a Turing machine with a state for each of those strings. As long as the state corresponds to a string of *less* than $n$ symbols it will move right and switch to a state that encodes the prefix of the input it has seen up until now.

When it is in a state that corresponds to a full length-$n$ string, the machine will halt and *accept* if the string it saw is in the language and it's currently reading a blank square; otherwise it will *reject*.

Comment: Thanks for the explanation. I understood most of it. Going along it, is the complement of a finite language also always decidable? Why so?

Comment: @Raj: Yes, the complement of a decidable language is always decidable. Just take a Turing machine for the first language and interchange which of the halting states you consider to accept and which you consider to reject. (These details depend on _exactly_ how you define what it means for a Turing machine to recognize a language, but it is generally close to that simple).

Comment: But could it be turing recognizable but not decidable? I also mean that there is a infinite set of String in the language

Comment: @Raj: I'm not quite sure what your question is, but note: (a) Not every infinite languages is the complement of a finite one.  (b) "Decidable" means that there is a Turing machine which _always stops_ and decides the language. (b) "Turing recognizable" often means that there's a Turing machine that stops on every input in the language and diverges on every other input. The complement of a Turing recognizable language is not necessarily Turing recognizable.

Answer (score 1):

Here are two short proofs to answer your questions:

Given a finite language we know that there are a finite number of strings in it and that these strings are of finite length.  Therefore we can describe this language by either a DFA or a regular expression.  Regular expressions and DFAs describe regular languages which are a subset of decidable languages, hence decidable. $\Box$

In regard to your second question, we know that DFAs are closed under complement and decidable eg switch accept and reject states.  Since we can express finite languages as DFAs, finite languages are closed under complement and are decidable. $\Box$