# Turing decidability

Tags: formal-languages, turing-machines

Consider intermediate chess board configuration.
L={w|w represents a board configuration, and white is guaranteed to win if it is white’s move and white plays optimally}
Is L decidable, recognizable or neither? And why :)

Comment: This is trivially decidable because there are only finite many positions in chess. With backtracking, we can fully solve every position in principle.

Comment: Yeah. I think the language has really weird formulation...

Comment: Also , $L$ is clearly recognizable because we can decide for each position, whether it is in $L$ or not.

Comment: And does it imply that something is recognizable if it is decidable?

Answer (score 0):

Note that any every finite language is decidable (check [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1272165/why-are-every-finite-language-decidable)), We already know all the possibilities for a chess board are finite, $L$ is a subset of them, obviously finite, therefore decidable.